# Oracle SQL - Errors ORA-00604 and ORA-00904 - WITH Clause and UNION two queries

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WITH SubQry AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
TBL1."IDNUM"

FROM
"LIBRARY"."SALES" TBL4 INNER JOIN "LIBRARY"."CUSTOMER" TBL1 ON TBL4."CUSTOMERKEY" = TBL1."CUSTOMERKEY"
INNER JOIN  "LIBRARY"."TIME" TBL3 ON TBL4."DATEKEY" = TBL3."DATEKEY"
INNER JOIN "LIBRARY"."PRODUCT" TBL2 ON    TBL4."PRODUCTKEY" = TBL2."PRODUCTKEY"

WHERE
TBL1."COUNTRY" IN ('Austria', 'Denmark',  'Belgium')
AND TBL3."FISCALYEAR" BETWEEN '2011' AND '2016')


SELECT
T1."REGION"
, T1."COUNTRY"
, SubQry."IDNUM" AS "BOOKING_IDNUM"
, (CASE WHEN SubQry."IDNUM" IS NULL Then 'New' ELSE 'Existing' END) "BOOKING_FLAG"
, T1."IDNUM"
, T1."CUSTOMER"
, T1. "BUSSINESS"
, T1."PROJECTNUM"
, T1."PROJECTNAME"
, T1."PROJECTOWNER"
, T1."PROJECT_STATUS"
, SUM(T1."PROJECT_VALUE")
, COUNT(*) "TRANSACTION_COUNT"
, TO_CHAR(trunc(T1."CREATEDATE" / 100)) AS "YEARMONTH_CALENDAR"
, (CASE
WHEN T1."BUSS_ID" IN ('ABC', 'DEF')
THEN 'MID' ELSE NULL END) "DRIVE_TYPE"
, (CASE
WHEN T1."IDNUM" IN ('901023','1401516','2401056','2101444')
THEN 'VIP' ELSE 'Standard' END) AS "ACC_TYPE"
, T1."BUSS_ID"

FROM
"LIBRARY"."PROJECT_DETAILS" T1 LEFT JOIN SubQry  ON  T1."IDNUM" =  SubQry."IDNUM"

WHERE
T1."COUNTRY" IN ('Austria', 'Denmark',  'Belgium')
AND T1."BUSS_ID" IN ('ABC', 'DEF')
AND T1."CREATEDATE" >= '20160101'

GROUP BY
T1."REGION"
, T1."COUNTRY"
, SubQry."IDNUM"
, T1."IDNUM"
, T1."CUSTOMER"
, T1. "BUSSINESS"
, T1."PROJECTNUM"
, T1."PROJECTNAME"
, T1."PROJECTOWNER"
, T1."PROJECT_STATUS"
, T1."BUSS_ID"
, T1."CREATEDATE"

HAVING
SUM(T1."PROJECT_VALUE") > 0


UNION


SELECT
T1."REGION"
, T1."COUNTRY"
, SubQry."IDNUM" AS "BOOKING_IDNUM"
, (CASE WHEN SubQry."IDNUM" IS NULL Then 'New' ELSE 'Existing' END) "BOOKING_FLAG"
, T1."IDNUM"
, T1."CUSTOMER"
, T1."BUSSINESS"
, T1."PROJECTNUM"
, T1."PROJECTNAME"
, T1."PROJECTOWNER"
, T1."PROJECT_STATUS"
, SUM(T1."PROJECT_VALUE")
, COUNT(*) "TRANSACTION_COUNT"
, TO_CHAR(trunc(T1."CREATEDATE" / 100)) AS "CREATEDATE_YEARMONTH_CALENDAR"
, (CASE
WHEN T1."BUSS_ID" IN ('ABC', 'JKL', 'PQR')
THEN 'PRO'ELSE NULL END) "DRIVE_TYPE"
, (CASE
WHEN T1."IDNUM" IN ('901023','1401516','2401056','2101444')
THEN 'VIP' ELSE 'Standard' END) AS "ACC_TYPE"
, T1."BUSS_ID"

FROM
"LIBRARY"."PROJECT_DETAILS" T1 LEFT JOIN SubQry  ON  T1."IDNUM" =  SubQry."IDNUM"

WHERE
T1."COUNTRY" IN ('Austria', 'Denmark',  'Belgium')
AND T1."BUSS_ID" IN ('ABC', 'JKL', 'PQR')
AND T1."CREATEDATE" >= '20160101'

GROUP BY
T1."REGION"
, T1."COUNTRY"
, SubQry."IDNUM"
, T1."IDNUM"
, T1."CUSTOMER"
, T1."BUSSINESS"
, T1."PROJECTNUM"
, T1."PROJECTNAME"
, T1."PROJECTOWNER"
, T1."PROJECT_STATUS"
, T1."BUSS_ID"
, T1."CREATEDATE"

HAVING
SUM(T1."PROJECT_VALUE") > 0
```

Hello,

The above query consists of:

1. ***WITH CLAUSE*** - Purpose of this clause is to identify distinct `"IDNUM"` from customers who purchased items between 2011 and 2016.
2. ***1st Query*** - The Primary purpose of the query is to check if any of the selected `"IDNUM"` exist in the above WITH CLAUSE. Also, this query is supposed to check if selected `"IDNUM"` match specific `"BUSS_ID"` and flag these as `'MID'` in a column named `"DRIVE_TYPE"`.
3. ***2nd Query*** - This query does nearly the same thing as the 1st Query. The only difference is that it flags `"IDNUM"` as `'PRO'` in a column named `"DRIVE_TYPE"`.

You might have noticed that in both queries,  there is a common `"BUSS_ID": 'ABC'`

- ***1st Query*** - `, (CASE WHEN T1."BUSS_ID" IN ('ABC', 'DEF') THEN 'MID' ELSE NULL END) "DRIVE_TYPE"`
- ***2nd Query*** - `, (CASE WHEN T1."BUSS_ID" IN ('ABC', 'JKL', 'PQR') THEN 'PRO'ELSE NULL END) "DRIVE_TYPE"`

I have tried to UNION these queries to display each line, which falls into both "BUSS_ID", as two separate lines of results. In other words, if a single line would have the `"BUSS_ID" of 'ABC'`, then select statement would display it twice. One line with `"DRIVE_TYPE"` flagged `'MID'` and another flagged `'PRO'`.

Problem is, when I run the query I get the following errors:

> ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
>
> ORA-00904:"from$_subquery$_003"."DATEKEY_0_0": invalid identifier

What is more confusing to me, I can run combinations of ***WHERE CLAUSE + 1st Query*** or ***WITH CLAUSE + 2nd Query*** without any problems.
But when I try to run ***WITH CLAUSE + 1st Query + UNION + 2nd Query*** I get errors.

Comment: The query works for me on 12.1.0.2.  Can you reproduce the error on other databases?  Maybe there's a bug on your version or platform?  It might help to create a smaller, self-contained, reproducible test case.

Comment: @Jon Heller Unfortunately I am only allowed to pull the data from the database not amend it. However, what you are saying is valid point. If other things fail, I'll considering creating a test database but only as a last resort as it would take me too much time. 
Thank you for taking time and looking into this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the great thing about CTE.  Try this a re-write with 3 CTEs, I bet the error message will be better if you still get one

```
WITH SubQry AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
TBL1."IDNUM"

FROM
"LIBRARY"."SALES" TBL4 INNER JOIN "LIBRARY"."CUSTOMER" TBL1 ON TBL4."CUSTOMERKEY" = TBL1."CUSTOMERKEY"
INNER JOIN  "LIBRARY"."TIME" TBL3 ON TBL4."DATEKEY" = TBL3."DATEKEY"
INNER JOIN "LIBRARY"."PRODUCT" TBL2 ON    TBL4."PRODUCTKEY" = TBL2."PRODUCTKEY"

WHERE
TBL1."COUNTRY" IN ('Austria', 'Denmark',  'Belgium')
AND TBL3."FISCALYEAR" BETWEEN '2011' AND '2016'), Q1 AS (
   SELECT
   T1."REGION"
   , T1."COUNTRY"
   , SubQry."IDNUM" AS "BOOKING_IDNUM"
   , (CASE WHEN SubQry."IDNUM" IS NULL Then 'New' ELSE 'Existing' END) "BOOKING_FLAG"
   , T1."IDNUM"
   , T1."CUSTOMER"
   , T1. "BUSSINESS"
   , T1."PROJECTNUM"
   , T1."PROJECTNAME"
   , T1."PROJECTOWNER"
   , T1."PROJECT_STATUS"
   , SUM(T1."PROJECT_VALUE")
   , COUNT(*) "TRANSACTION_COUNT"
   , TO_CHAR(trunc(T1."CREATEDATE" / 100)) AS "YEARMONTH_CALENDAR"
   , (CASE
   WHEN T1."BUSS_ID" IN ('ABC', 'DEF')
   THEN 'MID' ELSE NULL END) "DRIVE_TYPE"
   , (CASE
   WHEN T1."IDNUM" IN ('901023','1401516','2401056','2101444')
   THEN 'VIP' ELSE 'Standard' END) AS "ACC_TYPE"
   , T1."BUSS_ID"

   FROM
   "LIBRARY"."PROJECT_DETAILS" T1 LEFT JOIN SubQry  ON  T1."IDNUM" =  SubQry."IDNUM"

   WHERE
   T1."COUNTRY" IN ('Austria', 'Denmark',  'Belgium')
   AND T1."BUSS_ID" IN ('ABC', 'DEF')
   AND T1."CREATEDATE" >= '20160101'

   GROUP BY
   T1."REGION"
   , T1."COUNTRY"
   , SubQry."IDNUM"
   , T1."IDNUM"
   , T1."CUSTOMER"
   , T1. "BUSSINESS"
   , T1."PROJECTNUM"
   , T1."PROJECTNAME"
   , T1."PROJECTOWNER"
   , T1."PROJECT_STATUS"
   , T1."BUSS_ID"
   , T1."CREATEDATE"

   HAVING
   SUM(T1."PROJECT_VALUE") > 0
), Q2 AS
(
  SELECT
  T1."REGION"
  , T1."COUNTRY"
  , SubQry."IDNUM" AS "BOOKING_IDNUM"
  , (CASE WHEN SubQry."IDNUM" IS NULL Then 'New' ELSE 'Existing' END) "BOOKING_FLAG"
  , T1."IDNUM"
  , T1."CUSTOMER"
  , T1."BUSSINESS"
  , T1."PROJECTNUM"
  , T1."PROJECTNAME"
  , T1."PROJECTOWNER"
  , T1."PROJECT_STATUS"
  , SUM(T1."PROJECT_VALUE")
  , COUNT(*) "TRANSACTION_COUNT"
  , TO_CHAR(trunc(T1."CREATEDATE" / 100)) AS "CREATEDATE_YEARMONTH_CALENDAR"
  , (CASE
  WHEN T1."BUSS_ID" IN ('ABC', 'JKL', 'PQR')
  THEN 'PRO'ELSE NULL END) "DRIVE_TYPE"
  , (CASE
  WHEN T1."IDNUM" IN ('901023','1401516','2401056','2101444')
  THEN 'VIP' ELSE 'Standard' END) AS "ACC_TYPE"
  , T1."BUSS_ID"

  FROM
  "LIBRARY"."PROJECT_DETAILS" T1 LEFT JOIN SubQry  ON  T1."IDNUM" =  SubQry."IDNUM"

  WHERE
  T1."COUNTRY" IN ('Austria', 'Denmark',  'Belgium')
  AND T1."BUSS_ID" IN ('ABC', 'JKL', 'PQR')
  AND T1."CREATEDATE" >= '20160101'

  GROUP BY
  T1."REGION"
  , T1."COUNTRY"
  , SubQry."IDNUM"
  , T1."IDNUM"
  , T1."CUSTOMER"
  , T1."BUSSINESS"
  , T1."PROJECTNUM"
  , T1."PROJECTNAME"
  , T1."PROJECTOWNER"
  , T1."PROJECT_STATUS"
  , T1."BUSS_ID"
  , T1."CREATEDATE"

  HAVING
  SUM(T1."PROJECT_VALUE") > 0
)
SELECT * FROM Q1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Q2
```

Also consider changing the first CTE to use a different name than IDNUM, maybe BOOKING_IDNUM

```
WITH SubQry AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
TBL1.BOOKING_IDNUM
-- etc
```